# iTunes Search API Error: HTTP ERROR 403

Tags: jquery, itunes

I had been using the API to find the images of the songs on iTunes. Now when I try to run the code, I get an error saying:

> Access to itunes.apple.com was denied You don't have authorization to
>   view this page. HTTP ERROR 403

This is the code that I have used:
https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack

This used to work perfectly before, don't know what happened now.

Is there any way to fix it? Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: That link works fine for me.

Any chance you've been overusing that API and have been blocked as a result?

Comment: Its working fine.. May be you are making more frequent requests.. So, your IP is blocked.

Comment: That is true. I have been making frequent requests. Is there any way to unblock it? Should I use a VPN or some proxy instead?

Answer (score 0):

I also have this issue, they are applying rate-limiting to the search endpoint, I cannot find any documentation about this, but I filed a bud and they responded to say the limit was 20 requests per minute and to use their Enterprise Partner Feed located here : https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-enterprise-partner-feed/

I haven't implemented it yet, but will do so soon as we're getting nothing but 403's all the time now.

I have tried proxy, but it doesn't seem to work either.